# How to check two values with one Column in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to check two values with one Column of database in codeigniter. There is 'add_date' column in database I want to check values coming from $daterange variable with 'add_date' Column. The $daterange variable is split into array by using  `$array = explode(' ', $daterange);`

Now I want to check the 'add_date' column with first index of $array and also with second index of  $array. But the $where does not gives actual value.

```
public function get_reports() {
    if ($this - > input - > post()) { //If Any Values Posted
        if ($this - > input - > is_ajax_request()) { //If Request Generated From Ajax
            //Getting Posted Values
            $daterange = $this - > input - > post('daterange');
            $array = explode(' ', $daterange);
            $where = array(
                'add_date' > $array[0],
                'add_date' < $array[1]
            );

            $this - > data['sales'] = $this - > Common_model - > select_fields_where_like_join("add_sales", "*", '', $where);
            $this - > show('reports/sales_reports', $this - > data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the expected output and how is the current output different?  have you `print_r($where);` to see if it is ok? also, you don't need spaces `$this - > something`

Comment: I think you should use `between` filter.

Comment: @Kelly First please provide us the format in which your date is stored in your db and also the format of the date which you are getting through post request.

Comment: both formats are same. database format is '09/11/2018' and from post the format is  also '09/11/2018'. @Varun.Kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply Replace this code

```
'add_date' > $array[0],
'add_date' < $array[1]
```

With this code. And I am Sure it will Works for you.

```
'add_date >'$array[0] ,'add_date <'$array[1]
```

Comment: Thanks @KellyMorrison